# Issues with session Data

Tags: php

Hi i have a login system the function to login is:

```
if($user_data > 0) {
        session_start();

        echo "SESSION STARTED OK";

    $_SESSION['touch_session_admin'] = true;

        $_SESSION['touch_session_fingerprint'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . PHRASE . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        echo $_SESSION['touch_session_fingerprint'];

    header('Location: index.php');


    exit;

} else {
   header('Location: index.php?error=Wrong Username/Password!!!');

}
```

I am storing some sessions variables touch_session_admin and a secure touch_session_fingerprint I am having some issues with cheking of this session its not working!

The code using to check is a simple CLASS

```
class SessionClass {

    // __CONSTRUCTOR  AS SESSION CHECK
    public function SessionClass() {
                session_start();
                // is the one accessing this page logged in or not?
                if (!isset($_SESSION['touch_session_admin'])
                    || $_SESSION['touch_session_admin'] !== true) {
                    session_destroy();
                    header('Location: login.php');
                    exit;
                }


                if (
                $_SESSION['touch_session_fingerprint'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . PHRASE . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
                    ) 
                {     // Checking finger Print  
                session_destroy();
                header('Location: login.php');
                exit();     
}
                }
}
```

Even we make it work is the code secure?

Comment: Where is is not working? Try to debug as much as possible by yourself please

Comment: Its working while i remove the finger print check

Comment: @FDL what you mean by Define secure?I dont see it anywhere?

Comment: First off you're outputting data before your header redirect

Comment: The last word of your question.

Comment: I put those for some test let me see

Comment: session_start should always be at the top of each page using sessions

Comment: `var_dump` the different variables / constants. Is the constant defined, has the remote address changed, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, here is some general advice about php:

- Do not call `header()` or `session_start()` after any output
- Constructors are `__construct()`, not `Classname()` like some other languages.

What are you trying to achieve with that fingerprint? Session are stored **server side**, so you don't need to hash it (At least, I don't see any benefit doing that), since your users **can't** directly access to it.

I suggest you to replace your code by something simpler, with no fingerprint, like:

```
if($user_data > 0) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['touch_session_admin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['last_user_agent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $_SESSION['last_ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

And

```
class SessionClass {

    public static function checkAuth() {
        session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['touch_session_admin'])) {
            session_destroy();
            $_SESSION = array();
            header('Location: login.php');
            exit();
        }

        if ($_SESSION['last_user_agent'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) {
            session_destroy();
            die("User agent has changed !");
        }


        if ($_SESSION['last_ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
            session_destroy();
            die("Ip has changed !");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will try this. if server have another PHP app using same variable touch_session_admin it cause any issue with my application?

Comment: Yes it can. If you are trying to prevent any conflict with some other apps in the same domain, the recommended way is to use `session_set_cookie_params`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Answer (score 0):

In this line you use the constant `PHRASE`, but I don't see `PHRASE` being defined anywhere.

`$_SESSION['touch_session_fingerprint'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . PHRASE . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])`

Do you have [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) suppressed? If you enable it you may see the actual error. Otherwise, check your log for a message.

Comment: its defined in another file define('PHRASE', "fw{ssswe:wZ~4WE-J!Ax|iK7#?a%jE6^8ILY1t;(L-}pW+zy7{1wq56pJ|E&n");